# Riddle for an rainy day

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> My first has green and yellow
>   To take you there and back.
>   My second is made up of three,
>   A king, a queen, and just one more.
>   My third is all about a message,
>   Conveyed in the nick of time.
>   My fourth is north of rain around,
>   A king in the making there.
>   My fifth is completely out at sea,
>   Travelling to the sunrise bright.
>   My sixth has giants and a seat,
>   And takes place in the north.
>   My seventh is a tale of war,
>   And tragic in the telling.

What am I? Please explain how your answer fits each line of the riddle.

Comment: @JoeZ. Chat's probably the best place for that.

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: __Riddle for an rainy day__ Is this usage of 'an' instead of 'a' intentional?

Comment: @CodeNewbie Yes ... see if you can work out why :-)

Comment: @JoeZ. I didn't see your original comment, but there's a [special chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24004/chat-about-sci-fi-and-fantasy-adventure-puzzles) for riddles with this kind of theme, if you're interested.

Comment: I really wanted "and just one more" to be "and jack", but then I realised the rest of it didn't rhyme.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is it this?

> You are discussing the Chronicles of Narnia, in the chronological order of the books.

My first has green and yellow
To take you there and back.

> [The Magician's Nephew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magician%27s_Nephew)
>  Yellow rings were used to travel to the magical world of Narnia and green rings to return.

My second is made up of three,
A king, a queen, and just one more.

> [The Lion, The Witch And The Wardrobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Witch_and_the_Wardrobe)
>  The lion (Aslan) is the <strike>rightful king of Narnia</strike> king of the jungle, Jadis is the White Witch who pretends to be the queen and one more points to other object in the title, which is the wardrobe.

My third is all about a message,
Conveyed in the nick of time.

> [The Horse And His Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Horse_and_His_Boy)
>  A lost prince is rediscovered and it's his timely warnings that prevent an invasion.

My fourth is north of rain around,
A king in the making there.

> [Prince Caspian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Caspian)
>  Prince Caspian is the king in the making.
>  EDIT: As per rand's comments, <del>"north of rain around" again seeks to sneak in the name of Narnia in anagram form.</del> "rain around" is a clue to find an anagram for rain, which is the country Iran. And the Caspian Sea lies to the north of Iran.

My fifth is completely out at sea,
Travelling to the sunrise bright.

> [The Voyage Of The Dawn Treader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyage_of_the_Dawn_Treader)
>  Prince Caspian sets out on a voyage by sea to find the seven lost lords of Narnia.
> EDIT: The sunrise bright is a reference to the titular ship, Dawn Treader.

My sixth has giants and a seat,
And takes place in the north.

> [The Silver Chair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silver_Chair)
>  A journey is taken to the giant lands to the north of Narnia. The seat is the titular silver chair.

My seventh is a tale of war,
And tragic in the telling.

> [The Last Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Battle)
> A huge battle takes place that ends in the destruction (and re-birth) of Narnia.

The title is misspelt intentionally

> because the letters '..an rain..' can be rearranged to form Narnia.

To conclude, I would like to apologize

> since I haven't personally read the series, so please feel free to correct my explanations.

Comment: Well done! You've got almost all of it. Just "north of rain around", "travelling to the sunrise bright", and the title left to explain (hint: anagrams). Also Aslan isn't the rightful king of Narnia (the kings are always human), but the lion is said to be king of beasts ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor: "travelling to the sunrise bright" is regarding the dispelling of darkness from Dark Island?

Comment: How did you get this so quickly if you haven't read the series?!

Comment: @Stacey: Not so quickly. I saw this question within 20 minutes of its posting. I had to work to think about 7. Tried fitting it into the days of the week, then the colours of the spectrum. When I tried fitting it into the Harry Potter series, I stumbled upon the Narnia series.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Simpler than that! Good job on the title; "north of rain around" is something similar.

Comment: "travelling to the sunrise bright" is a reference to the ship's name "Dawn Treader"?

Comment: "Travelling to the sunrise bright" was just meant to say they're travelling east, but it also works as a reference to the ship's name. "North of rain around" is more complicated than the title: it doesn't have "rain an" to make an anagram of Narnia this time. What could "rain around" mean (crossword-clue-style)?

Comment: @randal'thor: North specifying first letter, I get "N rain a" from "North of rain around" (which is an anagram for Narnia)?

Comment: To be perfectly honest (i've read the series), Only the first two stanzas were needed, after that everything just fell into place.

Comment: @CodeNewbie What's an anagram of rain?

Comment: @randal'thor: in air?

Comment: What geographical region is an anagram of rain, and what's north of it? I want you to get this so that I can accept your answer, but I don't want to help you *too* much! :-)

Comment: Iran is the country, with Caspian Sea to the north.